# Make Xubuntu 16.04 persist on Windows hdd

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, persistence

It's been quite some years since I last used a live system. I remember being able to achieve persistence in 2 ways:

- put the live image on the windows partition and save data in the live
  image itself
- save data to a file on the windows partition and keep
  the live image on removable media

#### Question 1: Is it possible to start Xubuntu Live (i.e. without installing it) directly from the hdd *using the windows bootmanager*?

#### Question 2: If not, can I save data to a file on HDD to achieve persistence?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot should answer your first question. You ask indeed two questions and I think both answers would need lot of details. Wouldn't it be better to split your question in two questions? Although I see the relation between the Questions...

Comment: I edited Q1 stating that I'd like to use the windows bootmanager